# How to sync FF simple-prefs

Tags: synchronization, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like to sync the settings of my Firefox addon using `require('sdk/preferences/service')`.

Here my non-working trial:
**package.json:**

```
    {
    "title": "Test",
    "name": "test",
    "author": "devname",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "lib/main.js",
    "engines": {"firefox": ">=38.0a1","fennec": ">=38.0a1"},
    "license": "MPL-2.0",
    "id": "test@devname.org",
    "permissions": {"private-browsing": true},
    "dependencies": ["addon-kit"],
    "preferences": [{
            "title": "Color 1",
            "type": "color",
            "value": "#000000",
            "name": "1"
    }]}
```

**lib/main.js:**

```
    const
        addonid = require('sdk/self').id,
        simprefs = require('sdk/simple-prefs'),
        simstore = require('sdk/simple-storage'),
        service = require('sdk/preferences/service'),
        store = simstore.storage
    ;

    service.set('services.sync.prefs.sync.extensions.' + addonid + '.syncy', true);

    simprefs.on('1', function() {
        simprefs.prefs["syncy"] = simprefs.prefs["1"];
    });
})();
```

So, when in the Addon-Manager I set pref 1 to color #777777 then pref syncy will get the same value (visible on the about:config page).
When I use 2 Firefox profiles and register with Mozilla for syncing and install this add-on on each of them I expect that changing this value on one profile will change it on the other (so the setting on about:config -> extensions.test@devname.org.syncy) - but it doesn't.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Mozilla Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/Sync/Addon_Sync) about conditions to synchronize add-ons between profiles:

> Currently, Sync will synchronize add-ons that meet the following criteria:
>   - Is an extension or theme (i.e. not a plugin)
>   - Is installed in the profile directory
>   - Is installed explicitly by the user inside of Firefox
>   - **Is installed from a trusted URI**

I think problem in 4th condition. During development your addon can`t be trusted for Firefox. But in the same article, there is a hint of a possible variant of the bypass 4th condition:

> **Why is Functionality Limited to Add-ons from addons.mozilla.org?**
>   First, this is only the default behavior. The *services.sync.addons.trustedSourceHostnames* preference is a comma-delimited list to allow other trusted hostnames.

Comment: thank you! This seems a good idea but I tried to get it working with changing this comma seperated string of trusted sources - but either I do it wrong or it's not working as expected. Any idea of how to extend the string " addons.mozilla.org"? -> " addons.mozilla.org,???" - Thx